# как лучше справиться с Out of memory exception

Tags: c#, outofmemoryerror

Приветствую всех. 
Делаю небольшую програмку, которая работает с данными (читает файлы и создает свои), пишу на C#. В процессе выполнения, создаю коллекцию

```
 SortedList<string, List<MqlTick>> tickData = new SortedList<string, List<MqlTick>>();
 SortedList<string, List<MqlRates>> ratesData = new SortedList<string, List<MqlRates>>();
```

которые заполняются далее. В проесе заполнения до гигабайта на тестовом примере возрастает объем задействованой программой памяти. Записи из представленных коллекций постепенно в свое время удаляются (но не все, по мере накопления нужных данных). Удалять из раньше не могу. В связи с чем собственно и возник вопрос, как бы мне справиться с образовавшейся проблемой, можете ли посоветовать что нибудь ?

Comment: как насчет использовать временные файлы?

Comment: Memory maped file или что то еще имеете ввиду ? 
У меня просто читается 14 файлов, а из них создается около 2 000 файлов не меньше столько временных файлов не хотелось бы плодить...

Comment: именно MemoryMappedFile я и имею ввиду. достаточно доступно и с примерами есть на msdn и на многих других ресурсах: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Меняйте алгоритмы. В худшем случае удаляйте из памяти временно не нужные данные и перечитывайте их потом. В качестве некрасивого решения, перейдите на 64 бита.

Comment: ещё один вариант хранить элементы коллекций в таблицах БД

Comment: Попробую наверное смену алгоритма работы. с Базами не охото возиться сейчас